# Options to mongoose connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've a question on `db: { safe: true }` - which is being passed as an option to `mongoose.connect` in my nodeJS and MongoDB project.

I have the impression that this option is obsolete. Is that the case ?
If yes, what was it replaced by?
If not, where can I find the details of this option?

Knowing that I spent the afternoon looking for this information.

Many thanks in advance to you!

Answer (score 1):

This behavior, "SafeMode" appears to be obsolete. This is the equivalent of `WriteConcern.Acknowledged`, which is the default now.

You can manage this behavior on a transaction basis now, read more about `WriteConcern` here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/